# Access 3rd Party Library within SuiteScript File

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitecommerce

How can I access a third party javascript library inside a SCA SuiteScript file (a SuiteScript Service)?

For example; I have added the third party library `js-sha256` to my SCA project in:

```
MyProjectRoot/
  Modules/
    third_parties/
      js-sha256@1.0.0/
         ..contains the library files
         ns.package.json
```

My service simply tries to import the library:

```
function service (request)
{
  'use strict';

  var sha256 = require('js-sha256'); // error occurs here when service is run
  ...
```

When the service runs it responds with:

> {"errorStatusCode":"500","errorCode":"JS_EXCEPTION","errorMessage":"Error: No js-sha256"}

**Any advice how I can use a third party library in my SuiteScript Service? How do I set it up?**

**Relevant Information:**

- I have done a full deploy but it looks like the third party library isn't on the server in File Cabinet.
- My `js-sha256@1.0.0/ns.package.json` content is:

  ```
  {
      "gulp": {
          "javascript": [
              "src/sha256.js"
          ]
      }
  ,   "jshint": "false"
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

In order to expose something server side your ns.package.json needs to have:

```
{
    "gulp": {
        "ssp-libraries": [
            "src/sha256.js"
        ]
    }
}
```

and your distro.json needs to list the module

```
"modules":{
    ...
    "third_parties/js-sha256" : "1.0.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a blog post on how to add third party libraries to SCA - https://3en.cloud/insight/2017/3/21/adding-third-party-libraries-to-suitecommerce-advanced

Comment: The above link is dead.